# Incorrect Syntax Near ')' When Using Two "In Clause" Separated by "OR" and "Append" in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, append

```
    var cmd = new SqlCommand();
    var sql = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    sql.Append("SELECT * FROM tbl_VSArticle WHERE ");
    sql.Append("Brand1 in (");
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < brandsList.Length; i++)
    {
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@" + i, brandsList[i]);
         if (i > 0) sql.Append(", ");
         sql.Append("@" + i);
    }
    sql.Append(") OR Brand2 in (");
    for (j = i + 1; j < brandsList.Length; j++)
    {
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@" + j, brandsList[j]);
         if (j > 0) sql.Append(", ");
         sql.Append("@" + j);
    }
    sql.Append(")");
```

For some reason, incorrect syntax near ')' appears when excuting the code. When I remove the second half and loop which starts from "OR Brand2 ......", everything works just fine but obviously doesn't search in Brand2.
Can someone please tell me where is the error that I can't see? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and inspecting the contents of the `sql` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you do `for (j = i + 1; j < brandsList.Length; j++)` but at this point `i` will be equal to `brandsList.Length + 1` from the previous `for` loop and thus this loop will be completely skipped resulting in `"...Brand2 in ()"`

You'd need to make it something like `for (j = 0; j < brandsList.Length; j++)` and then do `"@" + (i + j)` for the parameter name to get it to work but here's a cleaner way to create the parameters and the sql.  You don't need separate parameters for the two lists since they have the same values.

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand();
var namesAndValues = brandsList.Select((x,i) => new {Name = "@b" + i, Value = x});
foreach(var x in namesAndValues)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(x.Name, x.Value);
}

var commaParamList = string.Join(", ", namesAndValues.Select(x => x.Name));
sql = $"SELECT * FROM tbl_VSArticle WHERE Brand1 in ({commaParamList})) OR Brand2 in ({commaParamList})";
```